# javascript put all my decrypted html list into HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I'm really new into this, so I want to ask how to put all my decrypted html list into "id=player" because only the first part `<source src="m37" type="video/mp4" size="" />`is printed not the whole html list but when I'm using console.log() everything was showed up.

```
let encryption = new Encryption();
var decrypted = encryption.decrypt(encryptedString, nonceValue);
//console.log(decrypted);
document.getElementById("player").innerHTML = decrypted;`
```

my decrypted html
    `<source src="m37" type="video/mp4" size="" /><source src="m32" type="video/mp4" size="" /><source src="m23" type="video/mp4" size="" />`

into this

```
<video poster="<?php echo $posterimg; ?>" id="player" playsinline controls>

  </video>
```

Comment: What does this have to do with `plyr`, which is a package used with the R programming language?

Comment: Just to clarify, you have some encrypted html, let's call it `X`. And you want to decrypt `X` and insert it into / use it as innerHTML of the `<video id="player" ...></video>` element? But only the first `source` element remains / is inserted?

Comment: @Barmar I mean plyr video js player, tagdeleted for no confusion.

Comment: @wendelin yes only the first source is inserted but not the rest element.

Answer (score 0):

It add all sources in video

HTML

```
<video id="player1" playsinline controls></video>
<br>
<button  id="myBtn" >add src</button>
```

Javascript

```
document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", addSrc);

function addSrc() {
    console.log("click");
    let src = '<source src="m37" type="video/mp4" size="" /><source src="m32" type="video/mp4" size="" /><source src="m23" type="video/mp4" size="" />';
    let player = document.getElementById('player1');
    player.innerHTML = src;
}
```

fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/praveenptl71/to025egj/6/